# Eclipse just does not start up

Tags: eclipse, java

I recently uninstalled and then reinstalled Java on my machine and ever since, Eclipse just does not start up. I find this weird, because I uninstalled a different version of Java from the one that I use. I modified the eclipse.ini file, by adding the following:

`-vm`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_15\bin\javaw.exe`

This made no difference. I then tried to reset the JAVA_HOME variable and I tried both these things again, after reinstalling (well, unzipping) Eclipse again. None of this made any difference, which is why I'm posting this question. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using? Also, are you able to browse to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_15\bin\' on the command line?

Comment: Can you still run other java-based things? Try running an applet or an executable jar file. At least this will tell us if the problem is specific to Eclipse, or if it's with your overall Java install. (It's probably the latter, but it never hurts to check, right?)

Comment: @Sagar Yes, I am able to navigate to the file from the command line.

Comment: @Dam My Java install is fine. Infact, the reason I uninstalled Java in the first place was because the installation was corrupted. I could not run executable jar files, but Eclipse and Java programs ran fine. Now, that I have reinstalled Java, the jar files run, but everything else stopped.

Comment: Make sure that the -vm entry is in the top section of the eclipse.ini

Comment: Very helpful article "[Debugging a failed Eclipse launch](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled all the versions of Java I had installed and installed them again. I also deleted Eclipse and downloaded that again. Following this, I edited the eclipse.ini file to include the path the javaw.exe, as I mentioned in the question. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the path to `javaw.exe` is in `%PATH%` environment variable. Basically:

```
%PATH% = %PATH%;c:\path\to\jre\bin
```

You can configure this in the environment variables configuration and you can verify this by opening a command prompt and test if `java` is recognized as a command from inside an arbitrary path.

The `%JAVA_HOME%` should by the way point to the JDK's `/bin` folder, not the one of the JRE. Regardless, this environment variable is ignored by Eclipse since it comes with its own compiler.

Comment: The %JAVA_HOME% points to the JDK's bin folder. Could you tell me how exactly to configure the environment variables include the path to javaw.exe?

Comment: I have no idea what Windows version you're using, so here's just a [WinXP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) targeted document. How about calling `java` in cmd?